# JVM tuning in JBOSS AS 7

Tags: jboss, performance-tuning, java

Can anyone explain as to where and how do I configure the following JVM parameters to tune JBOSS. I am using the latest JBOSS AS 7.

I am using openJDK-6 on Linux.

The following are the parameters which I have used for tuning Tomcat-7 and I need to know how & where do I put these in JBOSS:

To configure Java heap:

```
-server -XX:NewSize=700m -XX:MaxNewSize=700m -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=200m 
-XX:SurvivorRatio=6 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=15
```

To Configure Garbage Collector:

```
-XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled XX:ParallelGCThreads=16 -XX:+CMSCompactWhenClearAllSoftRefs -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=85 -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark -XX:+CMSConcurrentMTEnabled -XX:ParallelCMSThreads=2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the default startup scripts it should be sufficient to put this in the environment variable "JAVA_OPTS".

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JavaOpts

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using `./standalone.sh` command to start and stop the server, will try your solution.

Comment: I gave all the values in `JAVA_OPTS` in `standalone.conf` like this `JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Duser.timezone=GMT -server -XX:NewSize=700m -XX:MaxNewSize=700m -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:SurvivorRatio=6 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=15 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled XX:ParallelGCThreads=16 -XX:+CMSCompactWhenClearAllSoftRefs -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=85 -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark -XX:+CMSConcurrentMTEnabled -XX:ParallelCMSThreads=2"`

Comment: After doing the above setting the server is not starting :-(

Comment: Exactly what is the failure? Some log entries? I think the most valuable parameters are "-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m" - drop the rest.

Comment: yes with these two the server starts. I didn't get anything in the logs when the server didn't start. Also I need to configure the garbage collector as well so it is required

Comment: Actually your answer helped. I missed a `-` before `XX:ParallelGCThreads=16` for garbage collector tuning, now it works fine. Accepting your answer. Thanks a lot cljik